# how to maintain history state by using react-router-dom among components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, browser-history

I have a use case in which i use useHistory hook to redirect and pass state between components.

```
/* first component */

const {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
const history = useHistory();
history.push({pathname: '/next',course: 'some value'});

/* second component */

const location = useLocation();
const value = location.course; /* return 'some value' */
history.push('/nextroute') /* redirects to the third component */
```

Now the problem occurs when i press go back button from the browser, the location state gets undefined. Now i have views in which i have to use 'history' to redirect and pass state to components. how can i maintain that state when i press the back button on the browser or when ever a page refresh happens. Also what other effect way is there to pass state for this specific use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly I think you are getting `undefined` because react router is overriding your course value.

Push your course value to the location.state instead of the location itself eg:

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/next',
  state: {
    course: 'some value'
  }
});
```

then you can access it in your next component with `history.location.state.course;`

You may be getting undefined because your are trying to go back to the first form and haven't yet set a state for that route yet.  You will first need to replace the state and then push to the new form like so:

```
// replace the current routes state
history.replace({
  pathname: "/",
  state: {
    courses: 'your stuff'
  }
});

//then push this state to your next route for use there
history.push({
  pathname: "/next",
  state: {
    courses: 'your stuff'
  }
});
```

Here is a simple example [Codesandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-history-example-fnndt).

Note: if you want a state object that will be specific to each route then use the location state to store your data.  If you have general state that will change and is not bound to a specific route I would use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) instead.

Here is an example of that in action [CodeSandbox With Context Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/persistent-form-with-react-context-6rcjs)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have three forms, i pass the information of one form to another using history, it works fine but when going back to the previous form the the information i passed through the history object gets undefined. How can i tackle that. Context API is fine, but how can i do it with history.

Comment: Your probably getting undefined because you haven't yet set the location state for the first form that you are on.  You will need to use history.replace and then history.push to your next form.  I updated the answer and the codesandbox and also added a codesandbox with an example of using react context for a persistent form.  Anyway hope it helps if you have any more questions let me know.

Comment: putting the values in state object did the trick thanks.